# Polymer 2.0 app crashes Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, polymer, internet-explorer-11, polymer-2.x

I have a polymer 2.0 app that is transpiled to ES5.  It works well in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome; however, when I open it in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7, 8.1, or 10, the program crashes.  Sometimes it will render without most of the styles, other times it will crash before the page is even rendered.  Once, it said that a script was running long and asked if I wanted to stop the script.  Doing this also crashed IE.

Since the developer tools won't open, I'm not able to debug this.  What suggestions would you have for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project's bower.json file, webcomponentsjs was only saved as a dev dependency. Changing this to a primary dependency, rerunning bower install, and then rebuilding the app has solved this issue.