# Polymer 2.0 Internet Explorer 11 Style Issue

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-11, polymer-2.x

I'm having an issue in IE11.  It seems like if an element imports "polymer.html" instead of "polymer-element.html", it breaks all of the styles.

My styles in IE11 weren't working, so I stripped the polymer element down to bare bones and have done to following to identify root cause:

> - Add import "polymer.html" | Result: Styles do not work
> - Change to import "polymer-element.html" | Result: Styles work
> - Add import to app-route/app-location, which uses "polymer.html".  |  Result: Styles break.
> - Add custom polymer element import which uses "polymer.html".  | Result: Styles break
> - Change custom polymer element import to "polymer-element.html".  | Result: Styles work

I'm transpiling to es5 the app and bundling it with the Polymer CLI version 1.1.0.

Is this a known issue?  And, is there a workaround for this?

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide!

Comment: This question has the same root cause and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360529/polymer-2-0-app-crashes-internet-explorer-11